# In JS how can I make a new child instance for a existing parent instance?

Tags: javascript

```
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Financial extends Person{
  constructor(salary){
    this.salary = salary;
  }
}

// demand and debt class
class DD extends Financial{
  constructor(amount){
    this.amount = amount;
  }
}
let jack = new Person('jack');
```

I have 3 classes which inherent each other.
I made an instance of first class(person),
now how can I make a new instance of DD class for jack?

I'm making a simple Accounting webApp and this is my problem.

Comment: You need a constructor that accepts a `Person` instance as a parameter.

Comment: I think your design doesn't make much sense. What does `Financial` mean as a subclass of `Person`? The same question, but with `DD`? What would an `.amount` of a `Person` be?

Comment: @Pointy my ultimate goal is: initialize the DD class in a way that i can use this code and get the desired value: jack.amount  (amount is DD property)

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Financial extends Person {
  constructor(name, salary) {
    super(name); // Call the constructor of the parent class
    this.salary = salary;
  }
}

class DD extends Financial {
  constructor(name, salary, amount) {
    super(name, salary); // Call the constructor of the parent class
    this.amount = amount;
  }
}

let jack = new Person('Jack');

//My new code
jack = new DD(jack.name,200,1350);

console.log(jack.amount);
```

I found the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).